# Input values in angular 4 is not showing as it showing in hard coded values

Tags: angular

I am facing unknown issue while development.

[image]

In above image, one can see input fields having value as well as hard coded value.Problem is hard coded values should reflect in input fields but all input values has values of last input fields.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';
    temlateInputs=[
      {"name":"Australia","bi":"33","ex":"0","br":"50","ot":"0","ab":"AU"},
      {"name":"Austria","bi":"55","ex":"0","br":"25","ot":"0","ab":"AV"},
      {"name":"Belgium","bi":"66","ex":"0","br":"25","ot":"0","ab":"BB"},
      {"name":"China","bi":"77","ex":"88.887","br":"30","ot":"0","ab":"CH"}];
}
```

Table

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let data of temlateInputs">
  <td>{{data.name}}</td>
  <td>{{data.bi}}
  <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="bi" [(ngModel)]="data.bi"      />
  </td>
  <td>{{data.ex}}
  <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="ex"  [(ngModel)]="data.ex"      />
  </td>
  <td>{{data.br}}
  <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="br"  [(ngModel)]="data.br"    />
  </td>
  <td>{{data.ot}}
  <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="ot"  [(ngModel)]="data.ot"     />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Strange thing, it is working perfectly in stackblitz

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-mxgmfz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) demo

Why I am facing such errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can only be possible if you have same input name,

Replace your code block with this and try :

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let data of temlateInputs;let i = index;">
    <td>
        {{data.name}}
        </td>
    <td>{{data.bi}}
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="bi{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="data.bi"      />
    </td>
    <td>{{data.ex}}
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="ex{{i}}"  [(ngModel)]="data.ex"      />
    </td>
    <td>{{data.br}}
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="br{{i}}"  [(ngModel)]="data.br"    />
    </td>
    <td>{{data.ot}}
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="ot{{i}}"  [(ngModel)]="data.ot"     />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Patata, Glad to know that it worked for you , waiting for approval :) , Happy Coding :) .

Comment: @VivekDoshi Ideally you shouldnt request an upvote. Good answer though.

Comment: @sabithpocker, OP has given me upvote and removed on answer accept that's why I was asking. :) Thanks for the appreciation